# Exclude column header when writing DataFrame to json

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, databricks

I have the following dataframe df1

```
SomeJson
=================
[{
         "Number": "1234",
         "Color": "blue",
         "size": "Medium"
     }, {
         "Number": "2222",
         "Color": "red",
         "size": "Small"
     }
]
```

and I am trying to write just the contents of this column to blob storage as a json.

```
  df1.select("SomeJson")
     .write
     .option("header", false)
     .mode("append")
     .json(blobStorageOutput)
```

This Code works but it creates the following json in blob storage.

```
    {
        "SomeJson": [{
                "Number": "1234",
                "Color": "blue",
                "size": "Medium"
            }, {
                "Number": "2222",
                "Color": "red",
                "size": "Small"
            }
        ]
    }
```

But I just want the contents of the column not the column Header as well, I dont want the "SomeJson" in my final Json. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want dataframe column to get appended, write your dataframe as `text` and not as `json`. It will only write the content of your column.

```
df1.select("SomeJson")
     .write
     .option("header", false)
     .mode("append")
     .text(blobStorageOutput)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional assumption to this question,

We derive JSON structure itself from the dataset and then we encounter this header scenario like here. We can follow the below approach.

```
spark.sql("SELECT COLLECT_SET(STRUCT(<field_name>)) AS `` FROM <table_name> LIMIT 1").coalesce(1).write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.json").mode("overwrite").save(<Blob Path1/ ADLS Path1>)
```

Output will be like,

```
{"":[{<field_name>:<field_value>}]}
```

Here the header can be avoided by following 3 lines (Assumption No Tilda in data),

```
jsonToCsvDF=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", "~").load(<Blob Path1/ ADLS Path1>)

jsonToCsvDF.createOrReplaceTempView("json_to_csv")

spark.sql("SELECT SUBSTR(`_c0`,5,length(`_c0`)-5) FROM json_to_csv").coalesce(1).write.option("header",false).mode("overwrite").text(<Blob Path2/ ADLS Path2>)
```